# What is the name of the track playing in episode 14?

Tags: music, code-geass

In *Code Geass R2*, episode 14, at time code 14:35, there is a track playing. It plays after Rolo kills the other children with Geass. The battle between Lelouch, Jeremiah, and V.V.

What is the title of this track?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked all soundtracks; it has not been released. People on anime forums confirm that (for example, here: http://forums.animesuki.com/archive/index.php/t-38178-p-4.html).

The only one is someone's edit [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUKJ4zQ0MKY).

Comment: Yeah, I had a brief re-listen through all four Code Geass OSTs too, and I didn't find it either. Aggravating as it is, I'm inclined to say this is the right answer. (By the way, it would be nice if you would include links to some of the anime forums where you saw people confirming this.)

Comment: Here is one, with track list and appearing in anime - http://forums.animesuki.com/archive/index.php/t-38178-p-4.html There were also the second one, if I remember good on MAL, but I couldn't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

It's an unreleased piece from the soundtrack called **Collective Subconscious**. You can find it here:

[Code Geass: Unreleased Album - 49 Collective Subconscious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBrFOFPTrGI&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf&index=49)